# How to use D3 clip path on image within a function

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to be able to mask images with a circle. I can do this with D3, however I'm having trouble working this into my update loop. Below is my best attempt:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmqs78b4/)

I have defined the clip path with id '#ellipse-clip', but when I set this as an attribute on my images, the clip doesn't take effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var w = 300,
      h = 200;
  var barHeight = 20;

  var data = 

  championsleague = [{
    "name": "Hart",
    "saves": "9",
    "total": "15",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  }, {
    "name": "Subasic",
    "saves": "6",
    "total": "10",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  },];

  premierleague = [{
    "name": "Neuer",
    "saves": "12",
    "total": "27",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  }, {
    "name": "Forster",
    "saves": "13",
    "total": "22",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
   }];


// config, add svg
  var canvas = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,70)");

// config, add groups

  var name_g = canvas.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(80,0)");

  var image_g = canvas.append('g');

  var clip = image_g.append("clipPath");

  var Scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 39]).range([0, w]);

 // function that wraps around the d3 pattern (bind, add, update, remove)
  function updateLegend(data) {

 // bind data

  var clip = image_g
      .selectAll('ellipse')
      .data(data);

  var image = image_g
      .selectAll('image')
      .data(data);

    var name = name_g
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(data);

    // add new elements

    name.enter().append('text');
    clip.enter().append('ellipse').attr("id", "ellipse-clip");
    image.enter().append('image');

    // update existing elements

    name.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .text(function(d) {return d.name;
    })
    .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) -10
     });

    clip.transition()
    .duration(200) 
    .attr("cx", 25)        
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) - 25
    })        
    .attr("rx", 30)        
    .attr("ry", 30);  

    image.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {return d.image;
         })
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) -50
    })
    .attr('width', 80)
    .attr('height', 80)
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#ellipse-clip)"); 

    // remove old elements

    name.exit().remove();
    clip.exit().remove();
    image.exit().remove();

    };

    // generate initial legend
    updateLegend(data);

    // handle on click event
    d3.selectAll('.opts')
     .on('click', function() {
     var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
        updateLegend(data);
     })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code is a bit confusing, with the multiple `g` all bound to the same data and having the text separate from the clipped imags. I'd probably restructure a bit to create a `g` for each player containing a clippath (with unique id), the image and the text...

**But** to answer your real question your SVG is improper.  In the end you need something like this:

```
<g>
   <clipPath id="ellipse-clip"> <!-- id on clipPath with ellipse as child -->
     <ellipse ry="30" rx="30" cy="-25" cx="25"></ellipse>
     <ellipse ry="30" rx="30" cy="75" cx="25"></ellipse>
   </clipPath>
   <image clip-path="url(#ellipse-clip)" height="80" width="80" y="-50" x="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"></image>
   <image clip-path="url(#ellipse-clip)" height="80" width="80" y="50" x="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"></image>
</g>
```

With this mind, here's updated code:

```js
 var w = 300,
      h = 200;
  var barHeight = 20;

  var data = 

  championsleague = [{
    "name": "Hart",
    "saves": "9",
    "total": "15",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  }, {
    "name": "Subasic",
    "saves": "6",
    "total": "10",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  },];

  premierleague = [{
    "name": "Neuer",
    "saves": "12",
    "total": "27",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  }, {
    "name": "Forster",
    "saves": "13",
    "total": "22",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Joe_Hart_69775.jpg"
  }];


// config, add svg
  var canvas = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,70)");

// config, add groups
 
  var name_g = canvas.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(80,0)");
    
  var image_g = canvas.append('g');
    
  var clipPath = image_g.append("clipPath").attr("id", "ellipse-clip");
  
  var Scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 39]).range([0, w]);

// function that wraps around the d3 pattern (bind, add, update, remove)
  function updateLegend(data) {

// bind data
      
  var clip = clipPath
      .selectAll('ellipse')
      .data(data);
      
  var image = image_g
      .selectAll('image')
      .data(data);
      
  var name = name_g
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(data);

// add new elements
 
  name.enter().append('text');
  clip.enter().append('ellipse');
  image.enter().append('image');

// update existing elements
     
  name.transition()
  .duration(200)
  .text(function(d) {return d.name;
  })
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) -10
  });
        
  clip.transition()
  .duration(200) 
  .attr("cx", 25)        
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) - 25
  })        
  .attr("rx", 30)        
  .attr("ry", 30);  
        
  image.transition()
  .duration(200)
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {return d.image;
  })
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * (h / data.length) -50
  })
  .attr('width', 80)
  .attr('height', 80)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#ellipse-clip)"); 

// remove old elements
     
  name.exit().remove();
  clip.exit().remove();
  image.exit().remove();

  };

// generate initial legend
   updateLegend(data);
    
// handle on click event
  d3.selectAll('.opts')
    .on('click', function() {
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(data);
  })
```

```html
<script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


  
<button class="opts champ" value="championsleague">Champions League</button>
<button class="opts prem" value="premierleague">Premier League</button>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: That's a really good answer, and it makes sense to do the grouping that way. Thanks so much

Comment: Would you mind helping me with one more thing? I've restructured my code to have a seperate group for each player (and will add the clip paths next). However the way I've done it has completely stopped my data from updating. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/3cpp4yyt/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate the comments too, very helpful. If you wouldn't mind, do you know where I should be using transitions to make them work? For example its used on ('.saves') class and I've also tried ('.player') but no luck

Comment: @user3821345, that is very, very strange (sorry I didn't notice it before).  If you write the transition out long form it works: https://jsfiddle.net/3cpp4yyt/4/.  The other version should work as well, though, I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! This has been great. Although for the transition I want it to work between the different values, not starting from 0 each time. It has me stumped, because I have it working fine on an older example. I will post as a new question. Thanks again

Comment: Ah! I think it was the unique keys in the data binding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103322/d3-transitions-not-working/35104221?noredirect=1#comment57929638_35104221

Comment: @user3821345, D'oh!  So obvious now.  Glad you got it sorted.